How do I change in Helm the default commands list from "Emacs Commands History" to the general "Emacs Commands"?
How do I change in Helm the default commands list from "Emacs Commands History" to the general "Emacs Commands"?
Description of problem:
I often run into trouble when I try to run some-command with M-x some-command RET, where M-x is mapped to the helm command helm-M-x.  Instead of executing some-command, Helm executes some-similarly-named-command, which is a command I have  recently used.
The reason is that, by default, Helm lets me choose from the "Emacs Commands History" list of commands, not the general "Emacs Commands" list of commands.
some-command was not used recently, so it does not appear in "Emacs Commands History".  Instead, it seems like this some-similarly-named-command is fuzzy matched with the text I provided, some-command, therefore command execution does not fail entirely and executes the alternative some-similarly-named-command.
